# How provide justify of items by the left (or right) edge in the Column/Row container?

Tags: flutter

Below is the source code of the function, which allows show the menu by clicking on the canvas. In this case, the menu is the modeless window.

[image]

```
  void _showModeless(BuildContext context) {
    _modeless = new OverlayEntry(
        opaque: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return new Positioned(
            top: 100.0,
            left: 100.0,
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                selectItem("properties"),
                selectItem("delete"),
                selectItem("zoom"),
              ]
            ),
          );
        });
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_modeless);
    _startWaiting();
  }

  GestureDetector selectItem(String text) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          //_lights = true;
          _closeModelessWindow();
          print('=== tap ===');
        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        child: item(text),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration (
          color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
        ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0)
      ),
    );
  }

  Row item(String text)
  {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize:       MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Icon(Icons.content_paste, color: Colors.white),
        new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 24.0, ),
          child: new Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I do not like that the items are located in the center of this window. How to move them to the left up to some vertical reference line?

Answer (score 0):

You can left-align the children of the Column using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` in the Column constructor.

Comment: Ok, this works, I've checked. Thank you. One more question: can I make the list scrollable if the number of items will exceeds a certain number, for example 8?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below approach to align left/right in column/row.

> **Column**

// for Left align

```
new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text('Building Name'),
          new Text(propertyModel.title),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

// for Right align

just change `CrossAxisAlignment.start` to `CrossAxisAlignment.end` in above code

> **Row**

// for Left align

```
new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text('Building Name'),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

// for Right align

just change `MainAxisAlignment.start` to `MainAxisAlignment.end` in above code

> For more reference Please refer [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) and [Row](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

Answer (score -1):

Add the `crossAxisAlignment` property to your `Column`

`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

Comment: That would put it at the top of the column.  See my answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant the `crossAxisAlignment`